# c++ code using std::cin as input crashes halfway

Tags: c++, crash

I am currently doing this exercise on codeabbey. https://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/greatest-common-divisor

Here is my code.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int cases;
    int gcd[cases], lcm[cases];
    std::cin >> cases;             //first input for number of data to be input
    for(int x=0; x<cases; x++) {   //loop number of times = to cases
        int a, b;                  //for storing the two numbers
        std::cin >> a >> b;
        int atemp = a, btemp = b;  //need to hold initial value of a and b for lcm
        while (a!=b) {             //basically to calculate gcd.
            if(a>b)
                a-=b;
            else if (b>a)
                b-=a;
        }
        gcd[x] = a;                //store gcd for this case.
        lcm[x] = atemp * btemp / gcd[x];  // store lcm
    }

    for(int x=0; x<cases; x++) {
        std::cout << "(" << gcd[x] << " " << lcm[x] << ") ";   //output gcd and lcm for every case.
    }
}
```

However, when I try running it and using the sample values that the website gave, it always crashes. Below is the list of values that I copied into my console as input.

```
22
567 10
38 2
4214 2150
489 7459
82 5069
4200 784
4720 1770
2200 1440
6637 1
4984 7
1197 525
9905 472
648 552
7068 5700
22 2
2610 2160
7 7874
3663 3267
25 75
5985 3402
3337 5751
998 7895
```

When I copied the whole chunk of values as input, it doesn't work. I tried typing in manually, and discovered that it always ends on line 11 of input, (the line that is 4984 7). I think my code is really simple that it shouldn't go wrong... so I am wondering if there is something I do not know of happening here.

Comment: `int cases; int gcd[cases];` exhibits undefined behavior. Not to mention, that VLAs are not supported by C++ standard, but it tries to create VLA of indeterminate size, due to the fact, that `cases` is uninitialized. Such issue doesn't have anything to do with `cin`.

Comment: You don't deal with cases where a or b <= 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that variable length arrays (VLAs) are **not** a feature of *standard* `C++`, although some compilers (like `g++`) do support them.

With this in mind, note that you are declaring your VLAs - each of size `cases` ***before*** you have assigned a value to `cases`! So, the arrays will have undefined (possibly zero) size.

To fix this, you should move the declaration of the arrays to ***after*** the line that reads the `cases` value:

```cpp
int cases;                    // Variable is declared here BUT HAS NO VALUE ASSIGNED
//int gcd[cases], lcm[cases]; // WRONG - what value is "cases?"
std::cin >> cases;            // First input for number of data to be input
int gcd[cases], lcm[cases];   // NOW we can declare the VLAs, knowing the "cases" value!
//...
```

However, to make your code compatible with **Standard C++** you should use the [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) container class; so, in place of:

```cpp
int gcd[cases], lcm[cases];
```

use:

```cpp
std::vector<int> gcd(cases), lcm(cases);
```

You can continue to access the elements of the two vectors using the `gcd[x]` syntax, as `std::vector` provides the `[]` operator.

Comment: Minor nitpick: "_So, the arrays will have undefined (possibly zero) size._" Since the value is indeterminate - any value has an equal probably to be inside `cases` variable, as any other value. There's nothing, in the standard, that increases the probability of zero-value in this case.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius You can't get much more minor than that, since the answer in no way indicates an increased probability of zero. .

Comment: @WhozCraig Not a criticism of your comment (which I find helpful, actually), but could you elaborate on how I could elaborate? The code change I've suggested is **all** that is required (after suitably moving the `cin >> cases;` line) for the code to work with the STL.

Comment: @AdrianMole you're correct. Noticed the `(cases)` now. Have a tick, sir.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's why I stated, that it's minor. I got the sense, from the quote, that I provided in my comment. To be more exact, due to the singling-out "zero" in "_possibly zero_". One could make the same statement with "-1", "-2", etc..

Comment: @Algirdas "Since the value is indeterminate - any value has an equal probably to be inside cases variable, as any other value." - Indeterminate values are not uniformly random values. They simply aren't real values because reading them causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @BessieTheCow Yes, that is true. Technically, one could implement a compiler, that performs any, undefined, action, upon reading the value containing indeterminate value, and still be standard compliant. It's just that, I didn't see such compiler in practice.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius That still doesn't mean you're going to get a uniformly random value. Modern compilers can take advantage of undefined behavior to optimize programs, so UB can have some surprising outcomes. Even if you don't consider optimizations, the value of an uninitialized stack variable is often going to be whatever that was on that part of the stack previously, which can be some constant value such as 0.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks for the help! It sucks that I knew about this already but couldn't notice it despite looking through my code multiple times. I will definitely switch to vector, thank you.